# MS Flow starting the same flow twice

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

Ok so i've got a flow that sends some emails, updates some items etc. Its a MS Flow (for sharepoint online) that starts on "Item created or modified".

I've got checks in place so a field change doesnt retrigger the flow (no problem there). My problem is that whenever i create a new item the flow starts twice, instantly. It doesnt even get to the point to which it modifies the item in the list (i'm also updating fields to make sure that modifying those does not retrigger the flow, which works perfectly).

Its so weird and i've got no idea why it happens. Why would it start twice ?

Comment: what condition you added so that flow should not trigger on item modified ?

Comment: I added a field that gets updated when the email is sent so the 2nd time the flow starts it checks if that field is empty or not. If the field is empty it means the flow didnt run yet, but if its not it shouldnt send the email anymore. The field works as expected, the problem is the flow starts twice at a 1 second interval and it doesnt even manage to get to the step where it changes the field (so its not starting because the item gets modified, it just starts twice for an unknown reason).

Edit: i've got at least 5 more flows that do this, none of them have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem and it was as weird as i thought it was. I had a old workflow running on it (SP Designer 2013 workflow) that was logging. Apparently that "logging" counts as modifying the item which is why it started the MS Flow twice instantly.

This is what i had to uncheck to fix the problem ->

[image]